# How to set break point to debug Firebase Functions in VS Code

Tags: node.js, firebase, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-functions

As suggested by the title. I hate console logs, really want to find a more effective way to debug Firebase functions. I came across to [this blog](https://medium.com/@david_mccoy/build-and-debug-firebase-functions-in-vscode-73efb76166cf) thanks to David Mccoy. He shows us how to use the `google-cloud/functions-emulator` package to enable the **debugging feature**. 
However, when I try to follow the instruction and install the package, I came across this warning message:

```
$ npm install -g @google-cloud/functions-emulator
npm WARN deprecated @google-cloud/functions-emulator@1.0.0-beta.6: Deprecating in favor of the Functions Framework and firebase-tools. See https://github.com/googlearchive/cloud-functions-emulator/issues/327
```

I follow the link to check out the new framework, but can't seem to figure out how to use it. I am wondering if anyone can tell me how to use this new Functions Framework and firebase-tools to **set breakpoints in VS Code**? THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Firebase has a cli to run emulators

```
firebase emulators:start
```

There is good documentation explaining how to work with it here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/emulator-setup

As the error message suggests, you will also want to install the `firebase-cli` (firebase-tools) to make use of these features instead of the older @google-cloud functions emulator
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am wondering if there is a more detailed explanation on how this can be hooked up with VS Code debugging feature.

Comment: Have you tried using it? what is the challenge exactly?